# Request for ancient history video lecture references

Tags: ancient-history, prehistory, resource

I just read a page on the Math Stack Exchange linking pages with videos of Math lectures and would love to have a similar thing for History--hopefully that's an acceptable "question" to ask here.  Also audio lectures would probably be good too.

The topic is a little huge, though, so since my current interests are in ancient history I'll restrict this post to resources for ancient history.

I'll provide the ones I already know about.

**Video**

[History of the World to 1500](https://youtu.be/r_w7pfulsn8)

Everything from [Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/user/crashcourse), which I  believe is the same that Khan Academy uses.

[Ancient Greek History](http://oyc.yale.edu/classics/clcv-205)

And of course there's everything you can get through open coursewares like [EdX](https://www.edx.org/) and [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/).

**Audio only**

[Scott Chesworth's The Ancient World Podcast](http://ancientworldpodcast.blogspot.com/)

A couple classes from Tara Carter at UCSD, hopefully the links hold up: [Prehistory and World History](https://diyscholar.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/new-ucla-and-ucsd-classes-start-march-28/)

Comment: No list of accessible ancient history resources is complete without Mike Duncan's *History of Rome* podcast.

Answer (score 1):

The crash course videos are very nice, you already mentioned them.

http://www.history.com/topics
Scroll down to get to the list of topics for Ancient History.

https://www.khanacademy.org/humanities/history/ancient-medieval/Ancient/v/standard-of-ur-c-2600-2400-b-c-e
This aren't many, but it's something

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend Coursera courses like:

[Ancient Egypt: A history in six objects](https://class.coursera.org/ancientegypt-001) by the University of Manchester, or

[Roman architecture](https://www.coursera.org/course/romanarchitecture) by the Yale Univ

There is also an introduction to Egyptology course by the Universitat Autònoma de Barcelona, which I quite like, but unfortunately this last one is only available in Spanish